# How to Change Mobile Menu Icon Using PHP (Toggling Hamburger Menu)

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

I'm using the hamburger toggling method from the AMP-WP website and replaced the text with a symbol ☰ to create the hamburger.

https://amp-wp.org/documentation/playbooks/toggling-hamburger-menus/

```html
<?php echo( '☰' ); ?>
```

Everything works great, apart from I'd like to change the symbol to ✕ when the menu is open/active.

What PHP is required to do this please?

Comment: DOM manipulation required, so the answer is done in HTML, CSS, and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a different approach where your icon is really a set of HTML elements where each line is separate and can be targeted by animation, CSS transforms in this case:

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('#hamburger-toggle');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('open')) {
    this.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
    this.classList.add('open');
  }
});
```

```css
#hamburger-toggle {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;   
}
.hamburger-line {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hamburger-line-1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.hamburger-line-1, .hamburger-line-3 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 200ms; /* this line animates the change in position */
  transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.hamburger-line-2 {
  transition: opacity 200ms; /* this line animates the change in opacity fading in/out the middle hamburger line */
}
#hamburger-toggle.open .hamburger-line-1 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transform: translateY(8px) rotateZ(44deg);
}
#hamburger-toggle.open .hamburger-line-2 {
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  opacity: 0;
}
#hamburger-toggle.open .hamburger-line-3 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotateZ(-44deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger-toggle">
  <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-1"></span>
  <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-2"></span>
  <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Simran, thanks for your advice. The reason I did it that way is because, while what you suggest is the most popular/traditional way, the official AMP Navbar does it using symbols and obviously using the code from their sites, I was thinking that surely it's only perhaps one or two lines of PHP to change text or in my case a symbol?

Comment: If I get stuck, though, I shall implement your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Just remember all PHP is rendered on the server so anything to do with user interaction and changing the appearance on the site is almost always going to be a CSS or JS thing.

Comment: Sorry, my PHP didn't show up - I've just added it again, in case you wanted to see it? I've managed to style it with CSS like you say, I just changed the font size, etc. It looks fine apart from this one little thing!

Comment: The documentation there seems to agree with me, you need some JS, they give you a jQuery solution right below where they say "This usually involves enqueueing some jQuery-based JavaScript code that does:". ;)

Comment: Agreed, but then they say... Since this custom JS is not available in AMP, an alternative is needed. :)

Comment: Sorry, I needed to read that again, not sure what to tell you since I am not familiar with AMP...

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help. At least I have a solution if I can't change my PHP.

Comment: I finally sorted my problem. What confused me was the official AMP-WP site was using PHP - probably for brevity, I thought I could alter the PHP. However, as a newbie I didn't realise that PHP only runs on the server. My simple solution was to place two divs in my button. Give them each a class and display the icons using CSS. Couldn't have been easier in the end!